# Zoom Product for models after ajax update for MULTIPLE IMAGES

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, e-commerce, dotnetnuke

Using a Hotcakes Commerce module for dotnetnuke.zoom image working correctly when product has one image. The jQuery library used for zoom is `elevateweb.co`. ([Added Zoom to product view with this tutorial](https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205426265-How-to-Add-Zoom-to-a-Product-Image)) In `product.js` code has been updated also

```
$('#hcProductImage').attr('src', data.MediumImageUrl);
$('#hcProductImage').attr('data-zoom-image', data.MediumImageUrl);
$('#hcProductImage').elevateZoom({easing : true});
$('#hcSku').html(data.Sku);
```

`data-zoom-image` attrib of image source updated correctly , but zoom show previous image after change model of product. after changing `data-zoom-image` attrib of image `elevateZoom` function has been called to update zoom . but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Hotcakes Commerce. But I think you have to re-bind the background image of the zoomed DIV.

```
$('.zoomWindowContainer .zoomWindow').css({ 'background-image': 'url(\'' + data.MediumImageUrl + '\')' });
```

This probably works best with same size images.

Comment: works like a charm , but why when i recall `elevateZoom` function after change `source` and `data-zoom-image`  it doesnt build background of css ?

Comment: I don't know. That was the first thing I tried also. It looked like when calling `elevateZoom` again it was adding an extra zoom-div. Not replacing the current one. Then it only still showed the first one with the old image.

Comment: may be it is a bug in JS library that it doesnt check if there is `data-zoom-image` tag to update and not create new one . for better performance and quality of zoom image `data.MediumImageUrl` should be replace with `data.OriginalImageUrl`